# Infragistics ultraoptionset - how to add & (item shortcut)

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

Anyone knows how I can add shortcut to item (normally I can select with alt-key) ?
For other controls it is sufficient to add &prior selected character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. First you should add ampersand (`&`) in front of a letter you need to be underlined. Then you should set `UseMnemonics` property of `UltraOptionSet` to `true` like this:

```
// Add some items
this.ultraOptionSet1.Items.Add(1, "&First");
this.ultraOptionSet1.Items.Add(2, "&Second");
this.ultraOptionSet1.Items.Add(3, "Th&ird");

// Turn on the mnemonics
this.ultraOptionSet1.UseMnemonics = true;
```

You can find additional information in the online documentation [here](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawineditors%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawineditors.ultraoptionset%7Eusemnemonics)

Comment: Thanks! 
UseMnemonics  -this was I looking for